# Trying to find data in a second workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where I am building an automated e-mail but I want that e-mail to contain data that is stored in a second workbook.  Please see my code below, I did change some variable names/data just for confidentiality so hopefully that doesn't make it too difficult to read.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button1_Click()
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set wb1 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\wb1.xls")
Set ws1 = wbStoreList.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim filePaths As Variant
Dim msg As String
Dim i As Integer

Dim objApp As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim fileName As String
Dim emailAddress As String
Dim subject As String
Dim name As String
Dim otherName As String
Dim rowNumber As Range

Set objApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

filePaths = Application.GetOpenFilename(MultiSelect:=True)

If (IsArray(filePaths)) Then
    For i = LBound(filePaths) To UBound(filePaths)
        Set objMail = objApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        fileName = Dir(filePaths(i))
        If (Len(fileName) = 8) Then
            emailAddress = "email" & Mid(fileName, 1, 3) & "@emailaddress.ca"
        ElseIf (Len(fileName) = 9) Then
            emailAddress = "email" & Mid(fileName, 1, 4) & "@emailaddress.ca"
        End If
        subject = "Confidential"


        With ws1
            'On Error Resume Next
            Set rowNumber = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(8, 10000)).Find(What:="311", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        End With
        MsgBox rowNumber

dataFound:
        objMail.Recipients.Add emailAddress
        objMail.subject = subject
        objMail.Attachments.Add filePaths(i)
        objMail.Body = name & ", " & "(" & otherName & ")" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please see attached file."
        objMail.Display
    Next i
Else
    MsgBox "No files were selected"
End If
End Sub
```

The error is on the line with:

```
Set rowNumber = .Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(8, 10000)).Find(What:="311", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can directly get the row number like that because `rowNumber` is a Range (according to your `dim` statement). Give it a try and break it down into two lines:

```
Set rowNumber = .Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(10000, 8)).Find(What:="311", LookIn:=xlValues)
```

and then

```
If Not rowNumber is Nothing then lngNumber = rowNumber.Row
```

Note that I am using a new variable which should be of type long.

```
Dim lngRowNumber as Long
```

By the way: in your case `Integer` would actually suffice over `Long`.

Comment: I tried that, and I still get the same error on the same line.

Comment: On which line? The line where you `Set rowNumber` or on the line afterwards where you are checking `If Not rowNumber is Nothing`?

Comment: The `Set rowNumber` line

Comment: Could it be that you mixed up row number and column number in the `Range`? `.Range(.Cells(8, 1), .Cells(8, 10000))` means effectively row 8 and column 1 through column 10.000 which yields column `$NTP$8` at the end. This can cause problems if you don't have an new `.xlsx` Excel file open (which can have more than 256 columns). Maybe you rather meant: `.Range(.Cells(1, 8), .Cells(10000, 8))`?

Comment: Wow....well apparently that was it!  You'd think there would be some kind of "unexpected return value" error or something like that.  In any case, thank-you so much for your help Ralph, really appreciate it! :)

Comment: Although, another issue cropped up now.  When I changed the line to have `What:=fileName` which is a String variable that is set previously in the code, I get a new error "Object varaible or With block variable not set"  

EDIT: nevermind, I'm dumb and removed the "set".....